# With Terraform, how does one go about recycling root EC2 instance volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm wondering if anyone has tackled making an EC2 root volume persistent, so that one may taint the instance resource and re-apply and the instance will use that volume instead of the ami's?

My understanding from the documentation is that aws_ebs_volume and aws_ebs_volume_attachment work only with non-root volumes.

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by "making an EC2 root volume persistent". Related concepts are snapshots and AMIs, which can be used as templates to create disks.

Answer (score 5):

Terraform's `aws_instance` resource requires an AMI, and the root device is always a new volume produced from that AMI's underlying EBS snapshot. This is (as far as I know) a limitation of the underlying EC2 API.

As you've seen, it's possible to attach an existing EBS volume to a running instance using `aws_ebs_volume_attachment` but there's no way to use an existing EBS volume as the root filesystem of a new instance.

[The official documentation on root volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html) states that the closest we can come to what you want here is:

- Shut down the old instance while retaining its root EBS volume.
- Create a snapshot of the old root EBS volume.
- Create a new AMI using the created snapshot.
- Launch a new image using that new AMI.

This sort of multi-step process is difficult to orchestrate using Terraform alone, since Terraform isn't able to keep track of it's position in such a process. However, a config like the following would allow you to achieve it with a bit of manual workflow when you need to replace the instance:

```
variable "source_volume_id" {
}

resource "aws_ebs_snapshot" "new" {
  volume_id = "${var.source_volume_id}"
}

resource "aws_ami" "new" {
  name = "from-${aws_ebs_snapshot.new.id}"
  virtualization_type = "hvm"
  root_device_name = "/dev/xvda"

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    snapshot_id = "${aws_ebs_snapshot.new.id}"
    volume_size = "${aws_ebs_snapshot.new_volume_size}"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "new" {
  ami = "${aws_ami.new.id}"
  # ...etc...
}
```

This config assumes that you've already manually terminated the old EC2 instance and noted its root volume EBS volume id. You then pass that volume id in via the `source_volume_id` variable and it will do the remaining steps.

Each time `source_volume_id` changes Terraform should repeat this process, creating a new snapshot, AMI and instance. If you run Terraform again with the same `source_volume_id` as most recently used, it should leave everything unchanged.

A weird gotcha with this semi-manual process is that it has a chicken-and-egg problem where on the first run you probably won't already have a volume to base your AMI on. In that case you'd have to initially comment out everything except the `aws_instance` resource, hard-code an AMI id to bootstrap with, and let Terraform create that initial instance. On subsequent runs you can then follow the process as described above.

As noted above, Terraform is not currently well-suited for this sort of problem. Given that there's some manual steps anyway, it may work out simpler to just script this entire process using a more imperative approach e.g. using one of the AWS SDKs with your favorite programming language, though using Terraform for part of the process does at least free you from the task of keeping track of previously-used snapshot and AMI ids to ensure that they get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, terraform's `aws_instance` requires an AMI and cannot start an instance from an existing EBS volume (may be checked in the [source code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/builtin/providers/aws/resource_aws_instance.go) of the resource).